# Angular $http not handling error

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

My angular app doesn't handle the errors in $http calls.

I have a `$httpProvider` where I return `$q.reject(response)` in errorResponse as required by documentation. In the console the angular just puts `angular.min.js:99 GET http://localhost:8080/my/api 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

**Code**

```
console.log('before');
$http.get('/my/api', function(response){
   console.log('ok');
   console.log(response);
}, function(response){
    console.log('not ok');
    console.log(response)
});
console.log('after');
```

I just get 'before', 'after' and the message above.

Also in the network tab I get the expected response from server with status 500 and a json content in the body.

Except for the $httpProvider's errorResponse without a return $q.reject(), what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have syntactical mistake, you should use `.then` function and then put success & error callback to them.

**Code**

```
$http.get('/my/api').then(function(response){
   console.log('ok');
   console.log(response);
}, function(response){
    console.log('not ok');
    console.log(response)
});
```

What I understood by your code/question is, you are expecting to get `error` callback function to execute, but it is not doing that. If I missed something then do ask same in comments.